# Unable to get execute result (SQL-Tools)

Tags: python, sqltools

I have retrieve a record from my database (sqlite). When I ran the following code:

```py
from sql_tools import sqlite
sqlite.connect("base.sqlite3")
names = sqlite.execute("SELECT * FROM NAMES")
print(names)
sqlite.disconnect()
```

It gives me an object instead of my result. How can I get my result instead of this object. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `.get` property. From version `1.0.0`, the execute command returns an `Exec` object instead of the result. This object has some properties & `.get` is one of them. This property will return you the result in the form of an np array.

Code:

```py
names = sqlite.execute("SELECT * FROM NAMES").get
```